# Should we need run queue listen command every time when we push jobs into Laravel queue?

Tags: laravel

My question is that if I push jobs in Laravel queue then is I need to run `php artisan queue:listen` command every time?

Answer (score 3):

No. You have to run `php artisan queue:listen` only once. If you push jobs in the queue your job has to be executed by the queue.

Run `php artisan queue:listen` in the background with [supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#supervisor-configuration).

Comment: Is Supervisor necessary?

Comment: Yes. With Supervisor you can run the laravel queue in the background. if you logged out, the laravel queue is still running. Take a look: https://pkrai.wordpress.com/2016/06/19/laravel-queues-with-supervisor/